# Call to a member function getBag() on null - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 7.0 and this error is shown whenever the @error blade directive is used inside a view.

I've done a fresh composer install already.

```
Call to a member function getBag() on null
```

This is happening without instantiating any Validation logic.

The code I'm using is:

```
@errors('main_error')
{{ $message }}
@enderrors
```

Comment: you did a fresh project install of Laravel? the `ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware is in the `web` stack in `app\Http\Kernel.php`?

Comment: all these routes you are hitting are in the `web.php` routes file?

Comment: @lagbox Yes to both, it was initially a fresh project install of Laravel and I've removed the vendor folder and ran a composer install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd tried adding an extra middleware in the RouteServerProvider, rather than using the existing middleware() function there and passing an array with my web and extra middleware.

What I did:

```
  Route::middleware('web')
            ->middleware('referral')
            ->namespace($this->namespaces['web'])
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

What I should have done:

```
 Route::middleware(['web', 'referral'])
            ->namespace($this->namespaces['web'])
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```