# Call to a member function getBag() on array error after upgrading to Laravel10 and Livewire 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

After upgrading my app to Laravel 10 and Livewire 3, I get this error on a page:

`Call to a member function getBag() on array`

The code that gives this error is just an `@error` directive on my blade file:

```
@error('firstName')
    <p class="mt-2 text-red-500 italic text-xs">
        {{ __('Please enter your first name') }}
    </p>
@enderror
```

where `firstName` is a public property on my component, with validation rules present.

```
public $firstName;
...
$rules =  [
    'firstName' => 'required',
    ...
```

It worked before the upgrade, and it worked after Laravel10 upgrade, so I think it is coming from Livewire 3.

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: see livewire validation documentation here:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/validation

and please post full validation code for more suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63474505/call-to-a-member-function-getbag-on-null-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a public property `$errors = []` declared in my component by mistake. That was causing that strange error. After I deleted that property, it all works perfectly fine.